# small boxes go out line of container

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwYE2.png)

I'm trying to make a dashboard
When placing small boxes in the board
The boxes that are in the new row go outside the bounds of the page
The boxes in the first row appear correctly, but the problem starts when they go down to the second and third row, and so on.....
How can I solve this problem please?`

```
    <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <!-- small box -->
            <div class="small-box bg-hc">
                <div class="inner text-hc">
                    <?php
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ticket_prices ");
                    $stmt->execute();

                    $total = 0;
                    foreach ($stmt as $srow) {
                        $subtotal = $srow['TicketPrice'];
                        $total += $subtotal;
                    }

                    echo "<h3>" . $total, 2 . " AED</h3>";
                    ?>
                    <p>Total Sales from products</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="../booking/index.php" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                        class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->
        <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <div class="small-box bg-hc">
                    <div class="inner text-hc">
                        <?php
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ticket_prices ");
                        $stmt->execute();

                        $total = 0;
                        foreach ($stmt as $srow) {
                            $subtotal = $srow['TicketPrice'];
                            $total += $subtotal;
                        }

                        echo "<h3>" . $total, 2 . " AED</h3>";
                        ?>
                        <p>Total Sales from products</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href="../booking/index.php" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                            class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ./col -->
            <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                    <!-- small box -->
                    <div class="small-box bg-hc">
                        <div class="inner text-hc">
                            <?php
                            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ticket_prices ");
                            $stmt->execute();

                            $total = 0;
                            foreach ($stmt as $srow) {
                                $subtotal = $srow['TicketPrice'];
                                $total += $subtotal;
                            }

                            echo "<h3>" . $total, 2 . " AED</h3>";
                            ?>
                            <p>Total Sales from products</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                        </div>
                        <a href="../booking/index.php" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                                class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ./col -->
                <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                        <!-- small box -->
                        <div class="small-box bg-hc">
                            <div class="inner text-hc">
                                <?php
                                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ticket_prices ");
                                $stmt->execute();

                                $total = 0;
                                foreach ($stmt as $srow) {
                                    $subtotal = $srow['TicketPrice'];
                                    $total += $subtotal;
                                }

                                echo "<h3>" . $total, 2 . " AED</h3>";
                                ?>
                                <p>Total Sales from products</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                            </div>
                            <a href="../booking/index.php" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                                    class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- ./col -->
                    <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                            <!-- small box -->
                            <div class="small-box bg-hc">
                                <div class="inner text-hc">
                                    <?php
                                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ticket_prices ");
                                    $stmt->execute();

                                    $total = 0;
                                    foreach ($stmt as $srow) {
                                        $subtotal = $srow['TicketPrice'];
                                        $total += $subtotal;
                                    }

                                    echo "<h3>" . $total, 2 . " AED</h3>";
                                    ?>
                                    <p>Total Sales from products</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                                </div>
                                <a href="../booking/index.php" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                                        class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- ./col -->
</section>`
```

Comment: Using a working snippet rather than posting a image, increase your chance to get better answer. Stack Overflow Community doesn't do the work for you. Before you post something, make sure you have had research on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML structure is wrong. You can see it clearly in sublime or vs code or any of the html editor.
Assuming that you are going to Loop either the 'Box' or the 'Row of 4 Boxes', I have re-structured the HTML without the "PHP" code.

**Looping Option 1 :**
Look for `<!-- Looping Option 1 -->`, You can loop the boxes from here.

**Looping Option 2 :**
Look for `<!-- Looping Option 2 -->`, You can loop the row of 4 boxes from here.

```html
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Lopping option 2 -->
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Lopping option 1 -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <div class="small-box bg-hc">
                    <div class="inner text-hc">
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p>Total Sales from products</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href="../booking/index.php" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                            class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Lopping option 1 -->

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <div class="small-box bg-hc">
                    <div class="inner text-hc">
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p>Total Sales from products</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href="../booking/index.php" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                            class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <div class="small-box bg-hc">
                    <div class="inner text-hc">
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p>Total Sales from products</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href="../booking/index.php" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                            class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <div class="small-box bg-hc">
                    <div class="inner text-hc">
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p>Total Sales from products</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href="../booking/index.php" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                            class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Lopping option 2 -->
    </div>
</section>
```